# Python calling a module

Tags: python

Im trying to call module but some reason its giving me error.
The data.py contains a list of items and in the main.py Im trying to iterate and print over the items.but I get the below error.

Error

```
Import error: No module named Basics
```

Both data.py & main.py are located in c:/python27/basics/

data.py

```
bob={'name':'bobs mith','age':42,'salary':5000,'job':'software'}
sue={'name':'sue more','age':30,'salary':3000,'job':'hardware'}
people=[bob,sue]
```

main.py

```
from Basics import data

if __name__ == '__main__':
    for key in people:
        print(key, '=>\n  ', people[key])
```

If I just give import data, then I get the below error

Name error:name 'people' is not defined.

**Update:**

New code:

```
from Basics import data

if __name__ == '__main__':

    for key in data.people:
        print(key, '=>\n  ', data.people[key])
```

TypeError:list indices must be integers, not dict

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the second part, the "people" object is a list containing two dictionaries.  So you want to do this:

```
for person in people:
  for key in person:
     print(key, '=>\n  ', person[key])
```

Answer (score 5):

You will need `__init__.py` in your Basics directory

And

you will need to have that directory in your `PYTHON_PATH` or `sys.path`

To use people you need to do either of these.

```
from Basics.data import people
```

Or

```
from Basics import data
print data.people
```

Comment: it worked now..but how do I print each element in the people key..I have added the code in the main section

Answer (score 1):

Did you make an `__init__.py` in `c:/python27/basics/` ?

Also it is probably good practice to make the case of the import `Basics` match the case of the directory `basics`.  It doesn't matter on windows I think, but it certainly will under unix.

Comment: where can I get the __init__.py file?

Comment: @user1050619 the `__init__.py` file in a module can be empty if you don't need to initialize anything when loading the module.